# Ask for a proof of logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function involving the difference of the psi and logarithmic functions

Tags: convex-analysis, special-functions, laplace-transform, digamma-function, polygamma

It is common knowledge that the classical Euler gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ can defined by
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma(z)=\int^\infty_0t^{z-1} e^{-t}\textrm{d}t, \quad \Re(z)>0
\end{equation*}
and the psi (digamma) function is defined by $\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$.

A non-negative function $f$ is said to be completely monotonic on an interval $I$ if $f$ has derivatives of all orders on $I$ and
\begin{equation*}
0\le(-1)^{n-1}f^{(n-1)}(x)<\infty
\end{equation*}
for all $x\in I$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$.

A positive function $f$ is said to be logarithmically completely monotonic on an interval $I$ if it is infinitely differentiable (smooth) and satisfies
\begin{equation*}
(-1)^k[\ln f(t)]^{(k)}\ge0
\end{equation*}
on $I$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$.

A logarithmically completely function on an interval $I$ must be also completely monotonic on $I$, but not conversely.

The Bernstein--Widder theorem reads that a function $f$ is completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$ if and only if it can be represented as a Laplace transform
\begin{equation}\label{Laplace-mu(t)-INT}\tag{1}
f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\textrm{d}\mu(t), \quad x\in(0,\infty),
\end{equation}
where $\mu(t)$ is non-decreasing and the above integral converges for $x\in(0,\infty)$.

For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, let
\begin{equation*}
h_\alpha(t)=t^{t[\psi(t)-\ln t]-\alpha}, \quad t>0.
\end{equation*}
It is easy to prove that the necessary condition for $h_\alpha(t)$ to be logarithmically completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$ is $\alpha\ge-\frac12$.

**Is the necessary condition $\alpha\ge-\frac12$ a sufficient condition for $h_\alpha(t)$ to be logarithmically completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$?**

In the paper [3] below, the function $h_\gamma(t)$ has been proved to be logarithmically completely monotonic on $(0,1)$, where $\gamma=0.577\dotsc$ is the  Euler-Mascheroni constant.

**A hint:** the function $t[\psi(t)-\ln t]+\frac{1}{2}$ is completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$. See the papers [6, 8] below.

References

1. C. Berg, *Integral representation of some functions related to the gamma function*, Mediterr. J. Math. **1** (2004), no. 4, 433--439; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-004-0022-6.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *A property of logarithmically absolutely monotonic functions and the logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function*, University Politehnica of Bucharest Scientific Bulletin Series A---Applied Mathematics and Physics **72** (2010), no. 2, 21--30.
3. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function involving the logarithmic and psi functions*, Global Journal of Mathematical Analysis **3** (2015), no. 2, 77--80; available online at https://doi.org/10.14419/gjma.v3i2.4605.
4. B.-N. Guo, Y.-J. Zhang, and F. Qi, *Refinements and sharpenings of some double inequalities for bounding the gamma function*, J. Inequal. Pure Appl. Math. **9** (2008), no. 1, Art. 17; available online at http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article953.html.
5. V. Krasniqi and A. Sh. Shabani, *On a conjecture of a logarithmically completely monotonic function*, Aust. J. Math. Anal. Appl. **11** (2014), no. 1, Art. 5, 5 pages; available online at http://ajmaa.org/cgi-bin/paper.pl?string=v11n1/V11I1P5.tex.
6. Feng Qi, *Bounds for completely monotonic degree of a remainder for an asymptotic expansion of the trigamma function*, Arab Journal of Basic and Applied Sciences **28** (2021), no. 1, 314--318; available online at https://doi.org/10.1080/25765299.2021.1962060.
7. Feng Qi and Chao-Ping Chen, *A complete monotonicity property of the gamma function*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **296** (2004), no. 2, 603--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2004.04.026.
8. Mansour Mahmoud and Feng Qi, *Bounds for completely monotonic degrees of remainders in asymptotic expansions of the digamma function*, Mathematical Inequalities & Applications **25** (2022), no. 1, 291--306; available online at https://doi.org/10.7153/mia-2022-25-17.
9. R. L. Schilling, R. Song, and Z. Vondracek, *Bernstein Functions---Theory and Applications*, 2nd ed., de Gruyter Studies in Mathematics **37**, Walter de Gruyter, Berlin, Germany, 2012; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110269338.

---

In the paper "Mohamed Bouali, *On some complete monotonic functions*, arXiv (2022), 16 pages; available online at [http://arxiv.org/abs/2206.01527v1"](http://arxiv.org/abs/2206.01527v1%22), this problem has been moved forward slightly as follows.

**Proposition 1.8.** For $\alpha\ge-\frac14$, the function $h_\alpha(t)$ is logarithmically completely monotonic on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Big thanks for all references !

Comment: @Dens This is academic standard and my own style. Welcome.

Comment: Would you care to check out my question regarding complete monotonicity https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4767589/64809?